# Perl module Image::Imlib2 trouble saving gifs

Tags: perl, image, save, gif, perl-module

I'm using the perl module [Image:Imlib2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Imlib2/) to resize photos. Here is the code:

```
#create thumbnail
my $old = Image::Imlib2->load("$upload_dir/$name");
my $new = $old->create_scaled_image(80, 80);
$new->save("$upload_dir/$thumbnail_name");
```

This code works fine when I am saving a jpg or png file, but whenever I save a gif, I get an internal server error. Here is the error I get in my apache log file:

```
Image::Imlib2 save error: Unknown error at /path/to/script/script.pl
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're reading a GIF, scaling it down, and trying to save the thumbnail as a GIF? Can you `load` and `save` a GIF without changing it?

Comment: I cannot. That also gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Imlib2 supports writing GIF files at all. From a rather [old mailing list posting](http://gallery.menalto.com/node/266):

> I discovered that Imlib2 has absolutely NO support for writing out gif files.

Furthermore, if you look at the source, you'll see a couple files of interest:

- `imlib2-1.4.5/src/modules/loaders/loader_png.c`
- `imlib2-1.4.5/src/modules/loaders/loader_gif.c`

Inside `loader_png.c` you'll find this:

```
char
load(ImlibImage * im, ImlibProgressFunction progress,
     char progress_granularity, char immediate_load)
{
    /*...*/
}

char
save(ImlibImage * im, ImlibProgressFunction progress, char progress_granularity)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

and inside `loader_gif.c`, you'll find:

```
char
load(ImlibImage * im, ImlibProgressFunction progress, char progress_granularity,
     char immediate_load)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

but no `save` implementation. So it looks like Imlib2 can read GIFs but can't write them and that's where your trouble lies.

I'd recommend that you switch to [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) and `Graphics::Magick`. GraphicsMagick is a fork of ImageMagick that is faster and has fewer bugs, this is what Flickr uses internally so it should be good enough for you. GraphicsMagick unfortunately uses the somewhat strange ImageMagick API but you can hide the ugly details behind a wrapper without too much difficulty.

Alternatively, save all your thumbnails as JPEGs or PNGs.